# My app doesn't build and I catch INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED in xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin, deployment

I can't build my app on 23 API but on 25 API everything alright. I see Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED] in output.
I've already tried to uninstall the app on my device etc.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="1.6.10" package="com.companyname.name" android:versionCode="70">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA" />
    <application android:allowBackup="false" android:largeHeap="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="name.Tots">
        <meta-data android:name="com.appodeal.framework" android:value="xamarin" />
        <receiver android:name="com.appodeal.ads.AppodealPackageAddedReceiver" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name="com.vk.sdk.VKOpenAuthActivity" />
        <activity android:name="tots.Splash" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="ru.ok.android.sdk.OkAuthActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="okauth" android:host="ok1156051968" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="tots.VKUserActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.vk.sdk.VKServiceActivity" android:label="ServiceActivity" android:theme="@style/VK.Transparent" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1386147548358168" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:exported="true" />
        <activity android:name="tots.PremiumContainer" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.Achievments" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.Chat" android:theme="@style/Theme.KeyboardActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
        <activity android:name="tots.PMChat" android:theme="@style/Theme.KeyboardActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
        <activity android:name="tots.PMList" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.FindGame" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:noHistory="true" />
        <activity android:name="tots.GameActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.Invitation" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:noHistory="true" />
        <activity android:name="tots.NotWinner" android:theme="@style/Theme.TranslucentActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.ExitLeave" android:theme="@style/Theme.TranslucentActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.GameChat" android:theme="@style/Theme.KeyboardActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
        <activity android:name="tots.ViewGames" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity android:name="tots.ProfileSettings" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:noHistory="true" />
        <activity android:name="tots.DotsSettingsContainer" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.NavSettings" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.Premium" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity android:name="tots.DotcoinsActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.SettingTabContainer" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.Top" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.Quest" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.LangSettings" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.Tutorial" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.UserInfo" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="tots.LinkGameActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="game.tots.ru" android:pathPrefix="/game/" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="tots.OkAuth" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.FbAuth" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.VkAuth" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.Users" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.Report" android:theme="@style/Theme.KeyboardActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
        <activity android:name="tots.WatchGame" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.WatchOnlineGame" android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="tots.SecondaryUser" android:theme="@style/Theme.TranslucentActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <service android:name="tots.GameStartService" android:stopWithTask="true"></service>
        <receiver android:name="com.companyname.game.tots.receiver.DeclineInvitereceiver" android:exported="false"></receiver>
        <activity android:name="com.vungle.publisher.FullScreenAdActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.InterstitialActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.VideoActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.LoaderActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="org.nexage.sourcekit.mraid.MRAIDBrowser" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity android:name="com.amazon.device.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="ru.mail.android.mytarget.ads.MyTargetActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity android:name="org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.activity.VASTActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.activity.VPAIDActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.networks.SpotXActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.ads.InterstitialActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.ads.android.view.UnityAdsFullscreenActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.ads.android2.view.UnityAdsFullscreenActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
        <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyOverlay" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyFullscreen" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyBrowser" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.vungle.publisher.FullScreenAdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.list3d.List3DActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />
        <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.OverlayActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.FullScreenActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <service android:name="com.yandex.metrica.MetricaService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:process=":Metrica">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="com.yandex.metrica.IMetricaService" />
                <data android:scheme="metrica" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="metrica:api:level" android:value="39" />
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="com.yandex.metrica.MetricaEventHandler" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name="com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.inmobi.rendering.InMobiAdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard|smallestScreenSize|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
        <receiver android:name="com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities.uid.ImIdShareBroadCastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.inmobi.share.id" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.inmobi.signals.activityrecognition.ActivityRecognitionManager" />
        <activity android:name="com.flurry.android.FlurryFullscreenTakeoverActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity android:name="org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.activity.VPAIDActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.networks.vpaid.VPAIDActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run the `lint` program on your `AndroidManifest.xml`, you'll see the following errors:

```
Scanning TestLint: .
Scanning TestLint (Phase 2):
TestLint: Error: Can't find API database; API check not performed [LintError]
TestLint: Error: No .class files were found in project "TestLint", so none of the classfile based checks could be run. Does the project need to be built first? [LintError]
AndroidManifest.xml:3: Warning: Not targeting the latest versions of Android; compatibility modes apply. Consider testing and updating this version. Consult the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc for details. [OldTargetApi]
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
AndroidManifest.xml:113: Error: Duplicate registration for activity com.vungle.publisher.FullScreenAdActivity [DuplicateActivity]
        <activity android:name="com.vungle.publisher.FullScreenAdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
AndroidManifest.xml:139: Error: Duplicate registration for activity org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.activity.VPAIDActivity [DuplicateActivity]
        <activity android:name="org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.activity.VPAIDActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
AndroidManifest.xml:11: Error: Permission is only granted to system apps [ProtectedPermissions]
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA" />
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
AndroidManifest.xml:40: Warning: Exported content providers can provide access to potentially sensitive data [ExportedContentProvider]
        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1386147548358168" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:exported="true" />
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
AndroidManifest.xml:125: Warning: Exported receiver does not require permission [ExportedReceiver]
        <receiver android:name="com.yandex.metrica.MetricaEventHandler" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        ^
AndroidManifest.xml:132: Warning: Exported receiver does not require permission [ExportedReceiver]
        <receiver android:name="com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities.uid.ImIdShareBroadCastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        ^
AndroidManifest.xml:117: Warning: Exported service does not require permission [ExportedService]
        <service android:name="com.yandex.metrica.MetricaService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:process=":Metrica">
        ^
AndroidManifest.xml:65: Error: Missing data element [GoogleAppIndexingUrlError]
            <intent-filter>
            ^
AndroidManifest.xml:65: Warning: Missing URL [GoogleAppIndexingWarning]
            <intent-filter>
            ^
6 errors, 6 warnings
```

Comment: Thanks, I had another problem. I was testing on 23 API android my app with 25 API support.