# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED on Relese Mode Android 6

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

This error only occurs in Android 6 and mode release. In android 8 you run perfectly.

This is my Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.anoep.serodee" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application android:label="Serodee.Android">
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

```
3>90% ... 71808kb of 79716kb copied
3>100% ... 79716kb of 79716kb copied
3> Deployment failed
3>Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output:  pkg:/data/local/tmp/com.anoep.serodee-Signed.apk
3>Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]
3>
3>   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
3>   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass94_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t)
3>   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
3>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I try with Lint and this are the errors

`Scanning bin: .
bin: Error: Can't find API database; API check not performed [LintError]
AndroidManifest.xml:3: Warning: <uses-sdk> tag should specify a target API level (the highest verified version; when running on later versions, compatibility behaviors may be enabled) with android:targetSdkVersion="?" [UsesMinSdkAttributes]
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
AndroidManifest.xml:6: Warning: Should explicitly set android:allowBackup to true or false (it's true by default, and that can have some security implications for the application's data) [AllowBackup]
 <application android:label="com.anoep.serodee.Android">
 ^
AndroidManifest.xml:6: Warning: Should explicitly set android:icon, there is no default [MissingApplicationIcon]
 <application android:label="com.anoep.serodee.Android">
 ^
AndroidManifest.xml:6: Warning: App is not indexable by Google Search; consider adding at least one Activity with an ACTION-VIEW intent filter. See issue explanation for more details. [GoogleAppIndexingWarning]
 <application android:label="com.anoep.serodee.Android">
 ^
1 errors, 4 warnings`

Some Idea?

Comment: are you sure you set "applicationId" for a release target?

Comment: One quick way to see what's going on is to use `{SDKPath}\tools\bin\lint` against your `AndroidManifest.xml` found in your `obj` folder. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546549/my-app-doesnt-build-and-i-catch-install-parse-failed-manifest-malformed-in-xama/43546917#43546917

Comment: @JonDouglas I've tried but I don't know what to do with the error.